# Add a textbox to excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I'm new to stackoverflow and this is my first post.
I am working on a project where I have select to select data from a Excel sheet and paste it into an another Excel which contains template. The data selected is stored in an intermediate XML which is stored in separate excel sheet. Since excel cell has got a character limit for 32767 characters so XML is split into substrings of 32767 characters and then each substring is stored in different cells. 
The problem is at the time of reading when all the strings are joined to get the complete xml it is getting corrupted. So I thought of textbox as a substitute to store this xml. Because textbox has fairly large character limit. 
So I want to add a textbox control to an Excel sheet. I am using C#. How to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Here is the existing code that is being used.

```
  private XmlDocument GetXml()
  {
      Excel.Workbook WB = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
      Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
      XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
      string strXml = string.Empty;
      int XmlColumn = 1;
      try
      {
          ws = WB.Sheets["XML"];
          while (ws.Cells[XmlColumn, 1].Value != null)
          {
              strXml = strXml + ws.Cells[XmlColumn, 1].Value.ToString();
              XmlColumn++;
          }
          if (strXml != "")
              xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXml);
          else
          {
              XmlNode RootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("R");
              XmlNode TaggingXmlDocNode = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
              xmlDoc.AppendChild(TaggingXmlDocNode);

              XmlNode RawExcel = xmlDoc.CreateElement("RawExcel");
              RawExcel.InnerText = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name;
              RootNode.AppendChild(RawExcel);
              xmlDoc.AppendChild(RootNode);

              ws.Cells[1, 1] = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
          }

      }
      catch
      {
          xmlDoc = null;
      }
      return xmlDoc;
  }

  private void SaveXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
  {
      Excel.Workbook WB = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
      Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
      string strXml = string.Empty;
      if (xmlDoc != null)
      {
          strXml = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
          ws = WB.Sheets["XML"];
          int XmlColumn = 1;
          string Temp = strXml;
          for (int Len = 0; Len < strXml.Length; Len = Len + 32700, XmlColumn++)
          {
              if (Temp.Length >= 32700)
              {
                  string s = Temp.Substring(0, 32699);
                  ws.Cells[XmlColumn, 1] = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf('>') + 1);
                  int EndPoint = s.LastIndexOf('>');
                  Temp = Temp.Substring(EndPoint + 1);
              }
              else
              {
                  ws.Cells[XmlColumn, 1] = Temp;
              }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
          XmlNode RootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("R");
          XmlNode TaggingXmlDocNode = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
          xmlDoc.AppendChild(TaggingXmlDocNode);

          XmlNode RawExcel = xmlDoc.CreateElement("RawExcel");
          RawExcel.InnerText = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name;
          RootNode.AppendChild(RawExcel);
          xmlDoc.AppendChild(RootNode);

          ws = (Excel.Worksheet)WB.Sheets.Add(After: WB.Sheets[WB.Sheets.Count]);
          ws.Name = "XML";
          ws.Cells[1, 1] = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
          //ws.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVeryHidden;              
      }
      WB.Save();
  }
```

Comment: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried adding a textbox to the sheet and writing the data to it. But it doesn't help because the textbox on excel sheet has got a character limit for 32767 characters similar to that of an excel cell.